# Liskov substitution principle, preconditions and abstract methods

Tags: c#, oop, abstract, design-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

Liskov substitution principle (LSP) says:

> Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.

In C#, I could violate the whole principle as follows:

```
public class A 
{
      public virtual void DoStuff(string text)
      {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
      }
}

public class B : A
{
      public override void DoStuff(string text)
      {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Length > 10);
      }
}
```

But, what would happen if `A.DoStuff` would be an `abstract` method:

```
public class A 
{
      public abstract void DoStuff(string text);
}

public class B : A
{
      public override void DoStuff(string text)
      {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
      }
}
```

Now `A.DoStuff` is *contractless*. Or its contract is just *everything allowed*.

So, is `B.DoStuff` precondition violating *Liskov substitution principle*?

Comment: `A.DoStuff` has no precondtion, while `B.DoStuff` does so you have strengthened it.

Comment: @Lee The discussion could be if an abstract method, being just *metadata*, couldn't be considered to not provide preconditions, because since it has no behavior, the fact that it doesn't provide a precondition shouldn't mean that *it has no preconditions*. I believe that it's a simple case but it might require a complex analysis to determine if it's really breaking LSP...

Comment: @InBetween why you dropped your answer?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by abstract methods providing metadata, but if a method does not explicitly state any preconditions then it has none.

Comment: @zerkms - abstract methods can have pre/post conditions the same as any other.

Comment: @Lee you should elaborate more on your last statement

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer see `ContractClass` and `ContractClassFor` attributes

Comment: @Lee With contract classes, even interfaces can have pre, post-conditions, and invariants...

Comment: Yep, and that's what they exactly meant - there should be no difference in how you treat a "normal" and abstract method or interface: if they don't have a precondition, then adding any* strengthengs it

Comment: Because the more I thought it through the more convinced I was that yes, it is in fact a LSP violation and that my answer is perhaps wrong. I'm still mulling it over...but I'll un delete the answer, open another point of view

Comment: I'm saying that pre/post conditions must be stated expiclity so by not providing any, you are implicitly stating there are none. `A.DoStuff` has no preconditions, while `B.DoStuff` does `B` is strengthining the precondition and violating LSP. `A.DoStuff` being abstract is irrelevant since abstract methods can have pre/post conditions like any other method.

Comment: @zerkms you dropped some comment where you defended the opposite arguing that implementations of interface methods might break LSP, and now you're stating that you would treat regular, abstract and interface methods without any distinction in terms of not violating LSP. I've opened this Q&A because I feel that it's not 100% clear, we can do mistakes in our arguments and it's about getting a convincent answer to my (or even our) concerns.

Comment: @Lee So when you create a contract class of a given interface, you would also violate LSP. An abstract method and an interface method are almost the same monster: in C#, they're just metadata.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'metadata'. If you create a contract class and provide a contract for abstract methods or interfaces then all implementations must respect that by not strengthening preconditions or weakening postconditions. In your example you aren't providing any preconditions for `A.DoStuff` so there are none and therefore none can be provided by any subclasses.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I dropped it because I forgot it is technically possible (I personally find pre/post-conditions for both abstract methods and interfaces awkward hence never used it).

Comment: @zerkms In my case I've found contract classes to be extremely useful, you can define how to implement your interfaces or abstract classes, not only *what* to implement

Comment: *Now `A.DoStuff` is contractless*. NO, no, no. `A` **is** the contract! In a general sense, every base class is a contract for its derived class.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on **what defines the contract**.

The LSP is a theoretical construct, it does not depend on a specific language or implementation, such as C#'s "Code Contracts" feature.

The contract can be defined by:

- the method name
- the method parameter names
- the method comment
- the return type and the method parameter types
- "explicit" contracts such as `Contract.Requires`

On the last two will be verified by the compiler. However, the first three can be part of the contract as well! Consider the following example:

```
public interface StuffContainer
{
    void Add(string text);

    // Removes a string that has previously been added.
    void Remove(string text);
}
```

The name and the documentation of the `Remove` method define a clear precondition. Verifying in an implementation that the string to be removed has previously been added does not violate the LSP. Verifying that the string has at least 5 characters would violate the LSP.

Comment: Note that I wanted to explain the whole concern with C# and code contracts to just discuss about the topic based on an actual sample.

Comment: Anyway, your veredict is that the whole case I've explained in my question wouldn't necessarily violate LSP?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: If your method is really called `DoStuff` and has no further documentation, then yes, it does violate the LSP (both your first and your second example). If you method is actually called `DoStuffOnLongString` and you somewhere defined that a "long string" is a string with more than 10 characters, then no, the LSP has not been violated (neither in your first nor in your second example).

Comment: My question was originated by this other Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40957842/411632 See my answer there. @usr raised a concern there: it violates LSP. I'm not saying that it doesn't violate LSP, but I found that it would be interesting to raise a new Q&A to document/analyze the particular case of abstract methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can break the principle very easily, not only in C#.

It only states:

> Subtype Requirement: Let phi(x) be a
>   property provable about objects x of type T. Then
>   phi(y) should be true for
>   objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

In your example the type B does not fulfill the property of offering a method `DoStuff` that works with short texts, despite its supertype A fulfilling it. So the principle is violated.

It's up to the programmer to uphold the principle. A property could also be "it does the right thing", which you could easily break by having a subtype with a wrong implementation of a method.

Comment: Well I said C# because I wanted to introduce a code snippet using C#! :)

Comment: Uhm, when you talk about my example, are you thinking about the abstract case?

Comment: I'd argue that for an abstract class there are no objects. So the principle does not apply.

Comment: So you're in the same line as @InBetween.

Comment: In the other hand, we might say that the next level of hierarchy after the first class to derive `A` is the class to which LSP should be applied. Well, actually, any hiearchy starting from `A` would work this way

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that it's not. An abstract method by definition has no preconditions because there is no implementation. It would be the same as arguing if implementing an interface breaks LSP.

Saying `A.DoSomething()` is contracless is an untrue premise. `A.DoSomehing()` is undefined, therefore it can not have a contract further than its signature.

Comment: I believe your answer introduces a good point to get to the right direction when you compare abstract and interface methods.